# índices de listas

Tags: python, python-2.7

As minha duas listas iniciais têm valores repetidos:
B_I=[Cab, Bou, Bou, RFF, RF1, Rf2, Cor]
Ba_F=[Bou, Zez1, Zez2, Praca, Sro, Sro, Falag]

Eliminei os repetidos, ficando com: 
Final=[Cab, Bou, RFF, RF1, Rf2, Cor, Zez1, Zez2, Praca, Sro, Falag]

Precisava de ficar no fim com 2 listas de índices das ocorrências em cada uma das listas iniciais, como:

B_I_final=[0,1,1,2,3,4,5] 
Ba_F_final=[1,6,7,8,9,9,10]

Tentei isto:
No_I=[]
for a in range(0,len(Ba_I)):
    for b in range(0,len(Final)):
        if Ba_I[a]==Final[b]:
            No_I.append(Final.index(b))
        else:
            No_I.append()
Não sei como fazer no else, ou seja, na situação em que o índice na lista inicial difere do índice na lista final eu queria que tomasse o valor do índice desse elemento na lista final..
Alguém sabe como fazer isto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> B_I = ['Cab', 'Bou', 'Bou', 'RFF', 'RF1', 'Rf2', 'Cor']
>>> Ba_F = ['Bou', 'Zez1', 'Zez2', 'Praca', 'Sro', 'Sro', 'Falag']
>>> Final = list(set(B_I+Ba_F))
>>> B_I_final = [Final.index(i) for i in B_I]
>>> Ba_F_final = [Final.index(i) for i in Ba_F]
```